# Get the IMEI and Serial Number of Connected [Android] Phone

Tags: c#, serial-number, imei

i am developing a WinForm C# Application that needs to read the IMEI and Serial Number of a Connected [Android] Phone. is it possible to do this ?

i found an existing application that Gets the IMEI and Serial Number of a phone but it is for iPhones only, and it uses the MobileDevice.dll of the iTunes.

so i am trying to do the same but for Android Devices.

hoping everyone can help me. thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

so i've found out about this [AndroidLib](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1512685) Library by Regaw Leinad of XDA and it somehow eased my problem. although im still missing how to fetch the IMEI of the Device, i am now able to get the Phone's Serial Number.